# How to give different backgrounds to the same component?

Tags: reactjs

Edited:
I am new to react, and so far couldn't find the answer to this question. I have a `<Box />` component, which renders some HTML.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Box extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box-wrapper">
                <div className="different-image-for-different-copies">

                </div>
                <div className="box-name">
                Golden Lion
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Box
```

On one page, I have three copies of the same component. I want to be able to give unique background-image to the inner  with the className `different-image-for-different-copies` in each of those three components without making a new component.

Component `<Box />` is the child of a component `<Wrapper />`. What I want exactly is to be able to change the background of a certain `<div>` located in the child `<Box />` component from the parent `<Wrapper />` component. For example:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
              <div>
                   <Box "some way to change the background of the inner div" />
              </div>
         )
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass you image as a props to your `Box` component. Then in your component, set its style like this:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.imageUrlFromProps})`}}>
</div>
```

That's a basic example but should help you get your image to show up.

Comment: And what if inside of the component I have two <div>'s, and that the second <div>'s background needs to be changed?

Comment: You can pass as many props as you want. Do the same inline styling with the other components using the other images.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prop to pass to the component which background image it should use and set it on your component using inline style. If the set of images is limited, the rendering could instead pick a CSS class to apply.

Comment: What if it needs to be done for just one <div> inside of the component?